Inconsistent android build size
I have build a simple 2D game with unity. When build for android, the build size is around 32 MB.

However when I install and run the app, we're looking about double the size.

(App - 60.22 MB, Data - 106 KB, Cache - 172 KB, Total - 60.49 MB)
I am using Samsung Galaxy A 40, but the same symptom keeps showing on other devices.
Where does the extra 30 MB come from? Why does unity create 106 KB data for seemingly no reason (I know this isn't much, but I can't find where those files are located)

It's not unusual for an installed program to be larger than the installer, since the installation package will often compress files for a smaller download size, but they need to be decompressed before being used. Is there a reason the 30 MB difference here looks unusual, in your estimation?

Data can be for example your stored data like unlocked lvls, highs ore, purchases

I used json for that but that also happened before
